# How to access passportjs strategy callback in router?

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I am developing Oauth authorization with passportjs in my application and I have a question: how to get the callback returned from the strategy in the router. Not much is written in the official documentation and I do not quite understand what is happening there.
So can I do it?

server code

```
import OsuStrategy from 'passport-osu';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import passport from 'passport';
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var sessions = require('express-session')
config();

export default class Server {
    private app: Express;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
    }

    async start(): Promise<void> {

    this.app.use(cookieParser());
        this.app.use(sessions({secret: "secret", cookie: { maxAge: 60000, secure: true }}))
        this.app.use(passport.initialize());
        //this.app.use(passport.session());

        const clientID = 'meow';
        const clientSecret = 'woof';
        const callbackUrl = "link";

        const strat: OsuStrategy = new OsuStrategy({
            clientID,
            clientSecret,
            // If you want to read a specific mode from the user instead of 
            // the default game mode, change this to match the appropriate game mode
            userProfileUrl: 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/v2/me/osu',
            callbackURL: callbackUrl
        }, (_accessToken: string, _refreshToken: string, profile: any, cb: any) => {
            console.log(profile);
            // we have a profile variable
            return cb(null, profile);
        });

        passport.use(strat);

        passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  return cb(null, user);
  
});
        passport.deserializeUser((user: any, done: any) => {
            done(null, user);
        });

    var session;
        this.app.get('/auth/osu', (_req: any, _res: any, next: any) => {
           
    next()
        
        }, passport.authenticate('osu'));

        this.app.get('/auth/osu/callback', passport.authenticate('osu', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req: any, res: any) => {
            // variable profile need to access here
            res.send("Success! ");
        });

        const host = '127.0.0.1';
        const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8001);
        this.app.listen(port, host);
        console.log(`Basic server listening on http://${host}:${port}`);
    }
}

new Server().start();
```